Firebase Eventarc function not triggered
why is this not working? I can see the "Sending eventarc" message and no error in the Logs Explorer confirming that the function sending the Eventarc is called but I don't see the message "Eventarc received" meaning that the eventarc function doesn't seem to be called. It looks like this might have something to do with the location, the location for my app is nam5. Thanks!
const { onCustomEventPublished } = require("firebase-functions/v2/eventarc");
const {getEventarc} = require('firebase-admin/eventarc');

exports.onEventArcReceived = onCustomEventPublished(
'test.eventarctrigger',
(event) => {
    console.log("Eventarc received")
    const eventData = event.data;
    console.log(eventData)
    }
)
exports.testEventarc = onCall(
    {cors: ALLOWED_ORIGINS},
    (request) => {
        console.log("Sending eventarc")
        try{
            getEventarc().channel().publish({
                type: 'test.eventarctrigger',
                data: {
                    message: 'Arc event Message'
                }
            });
        }catch(error){
            console.log("error ", error)
        }
    }
)


If publish() returns a promise, and it fails, then the try/catch won't pick that up.  You should use await or then/catch callbacks to find out if something went wrong with that call.

Thanks for the response, I don't 100% understand how using await would help, but based on the eventarc api it looks like the eventarc was sent, although the api doesn't provide details on the event. This has been frustrating, I've actually decided to write my own functions without the use of eventarc.
